replacing a continuous variable in OpenModelica using Ompython and pyfluent
I am co-simulating a model in OpenModelica and Fluent(CFD). My aim is to pass the mass of species (tracer) from Fluent to a multizone model in OpenModelica. The synchronisation time-step is at every 1s. The stop-time of simulation is 10s. Is there any way to save the sate of variables such as the mass of the zones from the previous time-step without resetting the .mat file in OpenModelica at the start of the next synchronisation time-step?
